# Multilevel list starting at wrong number

Tags: microsoft-word, numbering, list

I'm using a multilevel list paired with a style based on headings to create my appendix in MS Word. Now, the problem is that the result I get looks like

```
Appendix A
 Appendix A.2
```

instead of

```
Appendix A
 Appendix A.1
```

I have tried going to "Define new multilevel list -> More -> start at " and select 1, the problem is that every time I save the document and close it, when I re-open it it will start again from A.2. Also right-clicking on the heading and use "set numbering value" does not solve the issue, as once again when I re-open the document the numbering is wrong.
As anyone ever encounter this strange behaviour/bug, and knows how to solve it?

Thanks in advance,
Gabriele

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Are you having the same issue if you enter the multilevel list manually (without defining/selecting a style)?

Comment: Just to check: In the More part of the box, have you also checked "Recheck List After" and specified the previous level (I would guess it's 1) as the level to cause restart?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio No, without selecting a style if works perfectly!

Comment: @yokki Yes, I've done it :)

Answer (score 0):

I am also having this problem except that my level keeps resetting to start at "B" after I change it to start at "A".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1150922)